# How to setup OpenCV with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-ide, opencv

**My question is how to do it (set it up), not if I can do it or with what Arduino.**

I've previously setup OpenCV with Visual Studio 2015. It was a tough one, but I made it through. Now I want to set it up so that it would work with the Arduino and its IDE.

***How should I proceed? Is there any specific things to do?***

My setup:

- Windows 7
- Arduino IDE 1.8.1
- OpenCV 3.1

Comment: Which Arduino? It's unlikely the AVR-based ones will have the resources to run this library. Not sure about the ARM-based units.

Comment: I wanted to use an Pro Mini, but I'll upgrade **if** necessary.

Comment: Not a chance. Maybe on a Raspberry Pi, but never an Arduino - unless it's one of these strange Intel things that are being marketed as Arduino these days. Basically you need an OS (Linux) to run OpenCV - something a *real* Arduino will never ever run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are thinking of using OpenCV with a "normal" Arduino, such as the Uno or Mega, then think again. OpenCV runs on a computer - be that a desktop computer or an embedded computer. Basically you need an operating system; "normal" Arduinos don't have an operating system.

It may be possible to run OpenCV on an Arduino that runs Linux (some of the strange Intel things that are being marketed as Arduino do, as does the Yún), but in that case you will be writing a Linux application, not working in the Arduino IDE. You would need to treat it as a normal Linux computer and use the normal Linux tools for developing on it (note that OpenWRT that the Yún runs is tricky to develop for - the best way is to cross-compile on a real computer running Linux using the OpenWRT "Buildroot" system).

Answer (score 1):

As some people said before, you just can't run OpenCV on Arduino.
but, you can use Arduino/Raspberry Pi to capture information and send it to a server for analysis. For example, Azure, Bluemix or your main computer.

In your case, I would use Raspberry Pi + camera to capture images/videos.
then, send it through Wi-Fi to a server. Then, on the server, process all images using OpenCV.